# Pacman en visual basic para aplicaciones

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Tengo un inconveniente estoy realizando un `pacman` en *visual basic* de `excel`, lo que tengo es que cuando aprieto las teclas se me mueve el pacman osea la imagen.

Tengo problemas para el asunto de los muros, el código lo tengo hasta el momento así

```
Select Case KeyCode
Case 37 'izquierda
pacmann.Left = pacmann.Left - 10

Case 38 'arriba
pacmann.Top = pacmann.Top - 10

Case 39 'derecha
pacmann.Left = pacmann.Left + 10

Case 40 'abajo
If (Label19.Top <> 222) Then

pacmann.Top = pacmann.Top + 10
End If
end select
```

En el `label19` es como una barra de laberinto entonces ese `label19` tiene como cabeza `222` entonces definí que si la cabeza del `label19` es diferente a `222` entonces deje bajar  pero cuando hago esto no me deja bajar a ningún lado.

¿Cómo soluciono el problema?

```
Case 40 'abajo
If (Label19.Top <> 222) Then

pacmann.Top = pacmann.Top + 10
End If
```

Comment: el label se mueve?

Comment: El label19 no se mueve solo seria como un muro del laberinto

Comment: Y entonces pq comparas su posicion, si deberia ser estatica?

Comment: @gbianchi mmmm....

Comment: No terminaria de entender tu problema o la logica de ver si rl muro sigue donde esta

Comment: @gbianchi bueno gracias

Comment: Y entonces como te podemos ayudar?

Comment: @gbianchi sabes como puedo remplazar el bounds en vba ?

Comment: If UnControl.Bounds.IntersectsWith(OtroControl.Bounds)) Then ...

Comment: asi se trabaja en visual studio pero no se que comando se usa en vba

Comment: No existe ese comando en vba. Deberias ver la posicion del sprite y fijarte si se cruzan con un algoritmo de cruce. Pero a mano. No hay una funcion en vba para objetos que compruebe esto